# C# How to update a List type variable

Tags: c#, list, ienumerable

**Scenario:** In my business layer, I have this variable called "groups" which is list of 4 different groups. Business requirement is to display groups in such way so that you only view group which you are assigned to. Tricky part is that a person could be part of more than one group. I have the below logic which works perfect for AppAdmin because they are able to view all the groups.

```
  if (IsUserInRole("Admin"))
  {
      groupsByMembersFirst = groupsByMembersFirst;
  }

  if (IsUserInRole("B"))
  {
      groupsByMembersFirst = groupsByMembersFirst.Where(g => g.GroupTypeName != "Bikes")
                                                 .ToList();
  }

  if (IsUserInRole("C"))
  {
      groupsByMembersFirst = groupsByMembersFirst.Where(g => g.GroupTypeName != "Cars")
                                                 .ToList();
  }

  if (IsUserInRole("N"))
  {
      groupsByMembersFirst = groupsByMembersFirst.Where(g => g.GroupTypeName != "NanoCars")
                                                 .ToList();
  }

  return groupsByMembersFirst;
```

groups contain all the  4 groups.

**Here's what I need help with:** 
Currently if user is in role B and C, it will only show  GroupTypeName cars because GroupTypeName List gets overwritten. How do I program it in such way that I just keep add/update the groupsByMembersFirst list so it does not overwrite it ? Help appreciated!

If I am not clear please let me know!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do a separate list which will hold the groups, in `if()` add items to that list, and then return:

```
var returnVal = new List<Group>();

if (IsUserInRole("Admin"))
{
    returnVal.AddRange(groupsByMembersFirst);
}
if (IsUserInRole("B"))
{
    returnVal.AddRange(groupsByMembersFirst.Where(g => g.GroupTypeName != "Bikes"));
}
if (IsUserInRole("C"))
{
    returnVal.AddRange(groupsByMembersFirst.Where(g => g.GroupTypeName != "Cars"));
}
if (IsUserInRole("N"))
{
    returnVal.AddRange(groupsByMembersFirst.Where(g => g.GroupTypeName != "NanoCars"));
}
return returnVal;
```

Comment: I am going to give this a try right now and post results!

Answer (score 3):

You should consider inverting your options, going from least specific, to most specific (`"Admin"`).

Start with a list and append with `AddRange`.

```
var validOptions = new List...

if (IsUserInRole("N"))
{
    validOptions.AddRange(...)
}
```